# Is there any GUI tool for Mutter customization?

Tags: customization, gnome-classic, mutter

I recently switched from GNOME Shell to the GNOME 3 fallback mode, and I'm using Mutter for my window manager. Is there any tool that will allow me to customize it to an extent, similar to the Compiz Config Settings Manager for Compiz?

Comment: No, there are currently no tools fo that.

Comment: No, [there is one](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/) but doesn't seemed to be usable yet (looking at the reviews) and [on GitHub](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-tweak-tool) too (the rule says "do not talk about it").

Comment: @clearkimura the github link was updated recently. Is it possible to post an answer now?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Not sure to which extent OP expect the tool to be able to customize Mutter window manager... Looking at early-2016 screenshots found in [this review on Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/reviews/linux/gnome-tweak-tool-review-501150.shtml), it doesn't seem to have detailed customization like CCSM has for Compiz. Also, I'd likely revisit GNOME in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and not anytime soon.

Comment: @clearkimura The OP hasn't responded to comment but also hasn't signed on here for 2+ years. The question itself is 5+ years old so the 2016 screenshots are likely not the version he was using. As such I'm voting to close this question as `not reproducible`.